# C# Uploading file to HTTPServer

Tags: c#, http

I need to write a httpclient to upload a huge file to the server using http. The code

```
public Stream function()
{
    string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);

    // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    request.Method = "POST";

    // Get the request stream.
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();

    // Write the data to the request stream.
    return dataStream;
}
```

Then, I return the dataStream to the caller of this function so that the application keeps writing to the stream using write. Then once done with the writing, GetResponse is called and then the stream is closed. But I get the exception

> ProtocolViolationException
>   at System.Net.HttpWriteStream.Write() while writing to the stream.

Kindly help.

Comment: Do you have any control about the server. Simply whipping up a server to check what error messages are thrown can be a huge help while debugging.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data)

Comment: @CodingBarfield: Files can't be uploaded with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: The server is able to create the file, but since the data isnt available it gives me the exception  "The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request"

Comment: @jgauffin - The link you had mentioned is not the one i am looking for

Comment: You might want to explain why.

Answer (score 0):

The `ProtocolViolationException` is probably thrown because the request method is GET or HEAD.

You must set the Method to POST like this:

```
// Set the 'Method' property of the 'Webrequest' to 'POST'.
request.Method = "POST";
```

See [HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc.aspx) documentation on MSDN.

Comment: The MSDN documentation mentions other conditions that can cause a ProtocolViolationException during a POST like: KeepAlive is true, AllowWriteStreamBuffering is false, SendChunked is false. Did you check that? Also, did you close the request stream before calling GetResponse()?

Comment: Yes. Those conditions have been checked.

Comment: you say you return the request stream to the caller of this function so that the application keeps writing to the stream. Do you write the exact number of bytes to the request stream as set in request.ContentLength? Also, did you close the request stream before calling GetResponse()?

Comment: when sendChunked is set to false, the number of bytes need not be set. Also since i will be keep writing to the stream I will not know the exact number of bytes.

Comment: Ok, now i'm also learning something new. I never really looked into what SendChunked does. I'm running out of ideas. Did you use tools like Fiddler to see what HTTP request/responses are actually send?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to debug the process when using a browser? 
This is a simple proxy allowing you to inspect http traffic.